# Working with CSVs: reading and writing data in the right order

Tags: python, csv

I have two `.csv` files related to data from Twitter.  One has the text of tweets, the other has the IDs for those tweets. The file with the IDs is the population from which the tweets in the other file are sampled.  I'm trying to write a script to read the text, search the other file for the corresponding ID, and then write a new `.csv` file that has both the ID and the text for the tweets in the smaller sample.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

# creates empty dictionary in which to store tweetIDs and tweet text
originals_data = {}

# declares an empty list to hold tweet text from coded datafile
# will be used to compare against the dictionary created earlier
coded_data = []
coded_all = []  # for all, not just text

# list to hold the IDs belonging to coded tweets for the round
tweet_IDs_for_coded = []

with open('first20.csv', 'rt') as round_in, open('gg_originals.csv', 'rt') as original_in:

    # reader object for gg_originals
    readOrigin = csv.reader(original_in, delimiter=',')
    # adds values from .csv file into the dictionary
    for row in readOrigin:
        originals_data[row[0]] = row[1]

    # reader object for round_x data
    readRound = csv.reader(round_in, delimiter=",")
    # appends the tweet text to a list
    for row in readRound:
        coded_data.append(row[0])

    # iterates over id:text dictionary
    for tweet_id in originals_data:
        # iterates over coded_data
        for tweet in coded_data:
            # When tweet in list matches text in dict, sends key to list
            if tweet == originals_data[tweet_id]:
                tweet_IDs_for_coded.append(tweet_id)

with open('first20.csv', 'rt') as round_in, open('test2.csv', 'wt') as output:
    # reader object for round_x data
    readRound = csv.reader(round_in, delimiter=",")
    # creates writer object to write new csv file with IDs
    writeNew = csv.writer(output, delimiter=",")
    # list that holds everything that's going into the csv file
    everything = []
    # sets row to equal a single row from round data
    row = next(readRound)
    row.insert(0, 'ID')
    # appends ID and then all existing data to list of rows
    everything.append(row)
    for i, row in enumerate(readRound):
        everything.append([str(tweet_IDs_for_coded[i])] + row)
    writeNew.writerows(everything)
```

The data for the population file (gg_originals.csv) looks something like this:

```
tweet_id_str,text
534974890168700930,abcd
534267820071084033,abce
539572102441877504,abcf
539973576108294145,abcg
529278820876943361,abch
529583601244176384,abci
535172191743397888,abcj
532195210059874304,abck
537812033895669760,abcl
,
,
```

The text-only file which is a subset of the population would look like this:

```
text
abcl
abci
abcd
```

What I have so far runs, it seems to get the correct IDs, and it even writes them to a new column in the new `.csv` file.  However, the IDs in the new file aren't in the correct rows - they show up in the rows for text that they don't actually correspond to, which is bad!

The new file *should* look something like this:

```
ID,text
537812033895669760,abcl
529583601244176384,abci
534974890168700930,abcd
```

Instead, it ends up like this:

```
ID,text
529583601244176384,abcl
537812033895669760,abci
534974890168700930,abcd
```

The correct IDs have been located, but they've been written to the wrong rows.

Comment: Please post sample dataset too. (from both files)

Comment: It would be helpful to include sample inputs, what you're *actually* getting as output and what you *expect* to get. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I think you're badly misusing your dictionary but a sample of the data would be helpful. You need only iterate through `coded_data` and then do `tweet_IDs_for_coded.append(coded_data[tweet])` on each iteration (potentially with some way to handle an exception if it's not found in dictionary). But I think you need the tweet itself as the dict key, not the id? This will need example data for further help.

Comment: I'll try to come up with some samples that work the same way as my actual data files.  Unfortunately, Twitter's TOS prevents me from sharing the data I'm actually using in one of my files

Comment: Your samples provided are enough for me, I am trying to replicate it now. I see that the output is scrambled, I will see if I can unpick it but I have only just finished creating the sample files so not looked properly yet. I still have a feeling the dictionary is involved in some way (dictionaries are un-ordered) but I'll look further.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.11.3, and I'm working in a Python 3.5 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this code does (I think) what you were looking to do. The reason I asked for your OS is that `wt` will give double-spaced csvs in Windows so I had to use `wb`. Also, inserting upper-case 'ID' in cell A1 causes type issues when opened with Excel. All fun :)

I ended up running out of time to track your error down and still give the answer so I have written the answer and I will go back if I get chance and highlight where your work went out-of-sync (I'd never come across SYLK error in Excel before so got distracted!).

I swapped your dictionary around. The tweet itself became the key of the dict. No more iterating through the dictionary. It also means you only need to open `first20.csv` once. Your original approach got a bit convoluted.

```
import csv

with open('gg_originals.csv', 'rt') as original_in:
    readOrigin = csv.reader(original_in, delimiter = ',')
    originals_data = {row[1]: row[0] for row in readOrigin}

with open('first20.csv', 'rt') as round_in:
    input_data = csv.reader(round_in)
    data_to_match = [row[0] for row in input_data]

compiled_list = []
for item in data_to_match:
    compiled_list.append([item, originals_data[item]])

with open('testoutput.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(compiled_list)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following disorder when I run this: (line 26) `KeyError: 'Input.tweet'`

Input.tweet is the header of the first row of the file.  When I delete the row with headers, I get a different error: (line 30) `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Line 26 and line 30 are both blank in the script I have given above (I still have it open in my editor) so I can't debug this. Did you copy my code with `import csv` as the first line?

Comment: `Input.tweet` is not a header in your example files. This works using the examples that you gave that I converted to CSV

Comment: Sorry about that.  Line 26 when I copy into my text editor is `compiled_list.append([item, originals_data[item]])`.  Line 30 is `writer.writerows(compiled_list)`.  And yes, I have `import csv`.

Comment: When I run with the sample files I provided, which I used with my code to generate the sample output, I get another error on line 30 (`writer.writerows(compiled_list)`): `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @jguberman You are very welcome :) We hit a bit of an issue with compatibility between Windows and Unix I think with my first answer :)